# Attach Authorization header for all axios requests

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I have a react/redux application that fetches a token from an api server. After the user authenticates I'd like to make all axios requests have that token as an Authorization header without having to manually attach it to every request in the action. I'm fairly new to react/redux and am not sure on the best approach and am not finding any quality hits on google.

Here is my redux setup:

```
// actions.js
import axios from 'axios';

export function loginUser(props) {
  const url = `https://api.mydomain.com/login/`;
  const { email, password } = props;
  const request = axios.post(url, { email, password });

  return {
    type: LOGIN_USER,
    payload: request
  };
}

export function fetchPages() {
  /* here is where I'd like the header to be attached automatically if the user
     has logged in */ 
  const request = axios.get(PAGES_URL);

  return {
    type: FETCH_PAGES,
    payload: request
  };
}

// reducers.js
const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  token: null
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case LOGIN_USER:
      // here is where I believe I should be attaching the header to all axios requests.
      return {
        token: action.payload.data.key,
        isAuthenticated: true
      };
    case LOGOUT_USER:
      // i would remove the header from all axios requests here.
      return initialState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

My token is stored in redux store under `state.session.token`.

I'm a bit lost on how to proceed. I've tried making an [axios instance](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#creating-an-instance) in a file in my root directory and update/import that instead of from node_modules but it's not attaching the header when the state changes. Any feedback/ideas are much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where are you storing the authorization token after the token is received from the server? localStorage?

Comment: in redux store session.token

Comment: I was doing this, but adding a nonstandard header like Authorization requires the use of a preflight OPTIONS request which can add a lot of latency to an app.  Now I'm trying to append it to the URL and keep it using the http "SIMPLE" method when possible.

Answer (score 474, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. Here, I have explained the two most common approaches.

1. You can use [axios interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) to intercept any requests and add authorization headers.

```
// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    const token = store.getState().session.token;
    config.headers.Authorization =  token;
     
    return config;
});
```

2. From the [documentation](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#global-axios-defaults) of `axios` you can see there is a mechanism available which allows you to set default header which will be sent with every request you make.

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;
```

So in your case:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = store.getState().session.token;
```

If you want, you can create a self-executable function which will set authorization header itself when the token is present in the store.

```
(function() {
     String token = store.getState().session.token;
     if (token) {
         axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
     } else {
         axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = null;
         /*if setting null does not remove `Authorization` header then try     
           delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
         */
     }
})();
```

Now you no longer need to attach token manually to every request. You can place the above function in the file which is guaranteed to be executed every time (**e.g:** File which contains the routes).

Comment: @awwester You don't need middleware to attach the token in the header. Attaching token in header is `axios.defaults.header.common[Auth_Token] = token` as simple as that.

Comment: Hi @HardikModha. If I use the default headers for the set token when I want to renew the token, it's can not set again into the header. is it correct? So i have to use the interceptors.

Comment: You might need to add `config.headers.Authorization = Bearer ${token}'`.

Comment: A minor gotcha: You will have to set default headers for each instance of Axios in your application separately if you are following second method. This took me a while to figure out.

Comment: @HardikModha what is `store.getState()`? is this your redux store? you don't store token in a cookie?

Comment: To avoid doing this for every instance of axios, you can do it in the login logic.

Answer (score 121):

Create instance of axios:

```
// Default config options
  const defaultOptions = {
    baseURL: <CHANGE-TO-URL>,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  // Create instance
  let instance = axios.create(defaultOptions);

  // Set the AUTH token for any request
  instance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    config.headers.Authorization =  token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '';
    return config;
  });
```

Then for any request the token will be select from localStorage and will be added to the request headers.

I'm using the same instance all over the app with this code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const fetchClient = () => {
  const defaultOptions = {
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH,
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  // Create instance
  let instance = axios.create(defaultOptions);

  // Set the AUTH token for any request
  instance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    config.headers.Authorization =  token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '';
    return config;
  });

  return instance;
};

export default fetchClient();
```

Comment: You should never store token in localStorage

Comment: @Amund Then where do you store it genius?

Comment: @Hackinet - the most secure way would be that server sets cookie with token. Important thing - cookie should have attributes "httpOnly" and "secure". And axios should not worry about token, because that cookie would be attached to request header.
The other approach (which usually is used by third party auth libraries, for example MSAL) - to store in session storage (and not in local storage). In this case would be necessary to define Authorization header as in Your example.

Answer (score 53):

The best solution to me is to create a client service that you'll instantiate with your token an use it to wrap `axios`.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const client = (token = null) => {
    const defaultOptions = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: token ? `Token ${token}` : '',
        },
    };

    return {
        get: (url, options = {}) => axios.get(url, { ...defaultOptions, ...options }),
        post: (url, data, options = {}) => axios.post(url, data, { ...defaultOptions, ...options }),
        put: (url, data, options = {}) => axios.put(url, data, { ...defaultOptions, ...options }),
        delete: (url, options = {}) => axios.delete(url, { ...defaultOptions, ...options }),
    };
};

const request = client('MY SECRET TOKEN');

request.get(PAGES_URL);
```

In this client, you can also retrieve the token from the localStorage / cookie, as you want.

Comment: What if you want to make the request.get() with "application-type" headers. With your approach the headers from defaultOptions will be overwitten by headers from request. I'm right? Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Similarly, we have a function to set or delete the token from calls like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default function setAuthToken(token) {
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = '';
  delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];

  if (token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `${token}`;
  }
}
```

We always clean the existing token at initialization, then establish the received one.

Answer (score 14):

The point is to set the token on the interceptors for each request

```
import axios from "axios";
    
const httpClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://youradress",
    // baseURL: process.env.APP_API_BASE_URL,
});

httpClient.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    config.headers.Authorization =  token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '';
    return config;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to call other api routes in the future and keep your token in the store then try [using redux middleware](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/applyMiddleware.html).

The middleware could listen for the an api action and dispatch api requests through axios accordingly.

Here is a very basic example:

**actions/api.js**

```
export const CALL_API = 'CALL_API';

function onSuccess(payload) {
  return {
    type: 'SUCCESS',
    payload
  };
}

function onError(payload) {
  return {
    type: 'ERROR',
    payload,
    error: true
  };
}

export function apiLogin(credentials) {
  return {
    onSuccess,
    onError,
    type: CALL_API,
    params: { ...credentials },
    method: 'post',
    url: 'login'
  };
}
```

**middleware/api.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { CALL_API } from '../actions/api';

export default ({ getState, dispatch }) => next => async action => {
  // Ignore anything that's not calling the api
  if (action.type !== CALL_API) {
    return next(action);
  }

  // Grab the token from state
  const { token } = getState().session;

  // Format the request and attach the token.
  const { method, onSuccess, onError, params, url } = action;

  const defaultOptions = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: token ? `Token ${token}` : '',
    }
  };

  const options = {
    ...defaultOptions,
    ...params
  };

  try {
    const response = await axios[method](url, options);
    dispatch(onSuccess(response.data));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(onError(error.data));
  }

  return next(action);
};
```

Comment: would you provide an example of how this is used ?

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you get a case where some of the requests made with axios are pointed to endpoints that do not accept authorization headers. Thus, alternative way to set authorization header only on allowed domain is as in the example below. Place the following function in any file that gets executed each time React application runs such as in routes file.

```
export default () => {
    axios.interceptors.request.use(function (requestConfig) {
        if (requestConfig.url.indexOf(<ALLOWED_DOMAIN>) > -1) {
            const token = localStorage.token;
            requestConfig.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        }

        return requestConfig;
    }, function (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to make new instance like i did below

```
var common_axios = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://sample.com'
});

// Set default headers to common_axios ( as Instance )
common_axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;
// Check your Header
console.log(common_axios.defaults.headers);
```

How to Use it

```
common_axios.get(url).......
common_axios.post(url).......
```

Answer (score 3):

```
export const authHandler = (config) => {
  const authRegex = /^\/apiregex/;

  if (!authRegex.test(config.url)) {
    return store.fetchToken().then((token) => {
      Object.assign(config.headers.common, { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` });
      return Promise.resolve(config);
    });
  }
  return Promise.resolve(config);
};

axios.interceptors.request.use(authHandler);
```

Ran into some gotchas when trying to implement something similar and based on these answers this is what I came up with. The problems I was experiencing were:

1. If using axios for the request to get a token in your store, you need to detect the path before adding the header. If you don't, it will try to add the header to that call as well and get into a circular path issue. The inverse of adding regex to detect the other calls would also work
2. If the store is returning a promise, you need to return the call to the store to resolve the promise in the authHandler function. Async/Await functionality would make this easier/more obvious
3. If the call for the auth token fails or is the call to get the token, you still want to resolve a promise with the config