# params object (API key) not being sent with axios.create

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

I'm making a get request to the MovieDB API using an axios.create instance. The params object I am attaching which includes the API key is not being sent with the requests.

The requests work fine when using axios.get but not with axios.create.

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3",
  params: {
    api_key: MY_API_KEY
  }
});
```

I am receiving error code 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: I don't think it's a syntax issue. 401 means not allowed to access the resource. You probably need a token to pass in the API as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attach Authorization header for all axios requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051291/attach-authorization-header-for-all-axios-requests)

Answer (score 1):

You can use paramsSerializer for this:

```
export const client = Axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
    paramsSerializer: (params) => {
        const serializedParams = qs.stringify(params, {arrayFormat: 'repeat'});
        return `${serializedParams}&APPID=${process.env.API_KEY}`;
    }
});
```

And sure you need to install [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) before implementing this:

> npm i qs