# Auth0 calling external API with NextJs

Tags: next.js, auth0, bearer-token

I'm struggling with calling my secure (secured by Auth0) backend API with the Auth0 Bearer token. I want to add the Bearer token to every request made to the API in my NextJs app. I can't find a solution for this anywhere

Method to retrieve accessToken

```js
 import { getAccessToken } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";

 ...

 const { accessToken } = await getAccessToken(req, res, {
    scope: "...",
 });
```

Comment: I've used nuxt-auth (not to be confused) and it attaches auth headers on every axios request. I imagine package next-auth does the same. You'd just have to configure it to use auth0 provider

Comment: Or if you're using axios just use an interceptor

Comment: @Issayah Do you have an example of this? I tried things like this but that doesn't worked out for me. Should be doing something wrong. When I tried the interceptor I got an error message that I can't change the request. And also, I needed the `req` & `res` to retrieve the accessToken

Comment: Truth be told I enjoyed using nuxt-auth more. Many of the things that it did made better intercept code than I code have written, like automatically refreshing the access token. Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051291/attach-authorization-header-for-all-axios-requests

Comment: Yeah I understand, Thanks for your fast reply. A link to a documentation would be nice too 

Answer (score 0):

You can create an axios instance:

```
  import axios from "axios";
  import { getAccessToken } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";
  const instance = axios.create();
  // Intercept all requests on instance
  instance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    return getAccessToken() // requires a Shopify App Bridge instance
         .then(({token}) => {
      // Append your request headers with an authenticated token
      config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
      return config;
    });
  });
  export default instance;
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, But how can I use this method in the interceptor:
```const { accessToken } = await getAccessToken(req, res, {
    scope: "...",
 });
```

Comment: @JespervandenMunckhof Did u find a solution to this ?

Comment: @souravlahoti I switched to [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware) instead of adding the token in the interceptor.