# Attach changing cookie to every Axios request?

Tags: react-native, authentication, axios

I'm making an app using Expo that has session cookie authentication. The backend is express sessions.

When a user sucessfully signs in, I store the token that's given by the server in Async storage on the device. When the user logs out or `checkAuth` fails for some reason (for example if the session has expired) I clear the token from Async storage and set the state to not authenticated. All this works good and seems to be robust.

Now I have encountered what might be a problem. For all other requests that aren't related to logging in or checking auth, I also need to send the token to server for authorization. For example when logging out.

I use Axios and need a way to attach the token that's *currently* stored in Async storage to the request. I have a custom Axios instance that's used in all requests. I'm thinking I could attach the token through that instance? Something like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const getStoredSessionID = async () => { // this function gets the auth token from storage
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('local_sid');
    return value;
  } catch (e) {
    alert("Async storage error")
  }
};

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://192.168.0.6:3002',
    timeout: 4000,
    headers: {'Cookie': `user_sid=${getStoredSessionID}`}
  });
  export default axiosInstance;
```

Does the code above make sense at all? Or is there maybe a better way? Please let me know if this is vague or if more information is needed. BIG thanks for any input!

The code above did not work as intended.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attach Authorization header for all axios requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051291/attach-authorization-header-for-all-axios-requests)

Answer (score 0):

I would have used interceptors for this. Axios has a nice way of adding logic to requests (and responses). See [here about interceptors](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors)

```
import axios from "axios";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const getStoredSessionID = async () => { // this function gets the auth token from storage
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('local_sid');
    return value;
  } catch (e) {
    alert("Async storage error")
  }
};
    
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://192.168.0.6:3002',
    timeout: 4000,
    headers: {'Cookie': `user_sid=${getStoredSessionID}`}
  });

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    config.headers.Cookie = `user_sid=${getStoredSessionID}`;
    return config;
});
```

Maybe consider adding validation to your stored session id, in case it could be tampered with...

Good luck